# Mostrar información del objeto recibido

Tags: laravel

Tengo una tabla con un registro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creé mi modelo llamado Section e hice la migración

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Section extends Model
{

}
```

y mi migración por si la necesitan saber

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateSectionsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('sections', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('titu_1_ing');
            $table->string('titu_1_esp');
            $table->string('desc_1_ing');
            $table->string('desc_1_esp');
            $table->string('fond_1_dsk');
            $table->string('fond_1_mbl');

            $table->string('titu_2_ing');
            $table->string('titu_2_esp');
            $table->string('desc_2_ing');
            $table->string('desc_2_esp');
            $table->string('fond_2_dsk');
            $table->string('fond_2_mbl');

            $table->string('titu_3_ing');
            $table->string('titu_3_esp');
            $table->string('desc_3_ing');
            $table->string('desc_3_esp');
            $table->string('fond_3_dsk');
            $table->string('fond_3_mbl');

            $table->string('titu_4_ing');
            $table->string('titu_4_esp');
            $table->string('desc_4_ing');
            $table->string('desc_4_esp');
            $table->string('fond_4_dsk');
            $table->string('fond_4_mbl');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('sections');
    }
}
```

Entonces tambien cree un controlador y para resumir solo pondre el metodo que me interesa:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Section;

class HomeController extends Controller
{       
    public function index()
    {
        $sectionInfo = Section::all();
        return view("home", compact(sectionInfo));
    }
```

De manera que tambien agregue esta ruta a mi web.php 
**Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');**

Ahora una vez armado como este rompecabezas (al menos para mi que soy nuevo) como accedo desde mi vista a ese objeto que le paso desde mi controlador? coloque todo por si acaso me salte algo o hice algo mal

Este es mi vista, bueno la parte del formulario ya que luego debo actualizar pero al menos debo saber que leo bien los datos

```html
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('home') }}">

                        <!-- BOTONES GUARDAR / CERRAR -->
                        <div class="row" style="    text-align: right;
                                                    margin-top: 1rem;
                                                    margin-bottom: 1rem;">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <button type="button" class="btn" style="background: #065e6e; color: white; width: 7rem;">CERRAR</button>
                                <button type="SUBMIT" class="btn" style="background: #00a751; color: white; width: 7rem;">ACTUALIZAR</button>
                            </div>    
                        </div>

                        <!-- TITULOS -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6" style="padding-left: 3px; margin-bottom: 1rem;">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="PRIVATE EXCURSSIONS IN SANTIAGO DE CHILE" style=" width: 100%;   padding: 0.3rem;   background: #e3e6e9;
                                                                                        border: solid 1px #8181825c;" text="PRIVATE ESCRUSSION IN SANTIAGO DE CHILE">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6" style="padding-right: 3px; margin-bottom: 1rem;">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Titulo Español" style="width: 100%; padding: 0.3rem;  background: #e3e6e9;
                                                                                    border: solid 1px #8181825c;">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- DESCRIPCION -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6" style="padding-left: 3px; margin-bottom: 1rem;">
                                <textarea name="message" rows="30" cols="80" style=" width: 100%; padding: 0.8rem;  height: 10rem; background: #e3e6e9; border: solid 1px #8181825c;">The primary objective of Pikun Mapu is to provide innovative and unique travel experiens fot the best value showcasing the most spectacular places, attractions and activities in Santiago de Chile</textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6" style="padding-right: 3px; margin-bottom: 1rem;">
                                <textarea name="message" rows="30" cols="80" style=" width: 100%; padding: 0.8rem;  height: 10rem; background: #e3e6e9; border: solid 1px #8181825c;">Texto Español</textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <hr/>
                        
                        <!-- CARGAR IMAGENES -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <h4>IMÁGENES DESKTOP</h4>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-6">
                                <h4>IMÁGENES MÓVIL</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" />
                                <br />
                                <div style="width: 5rem; height: 5rem;">
                                        <output id="list"></output>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" />
                                <br />
                                <output id="list"></output>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumiendo que quieres mostrar la data en la vista para el usuario, sería:

```
<ul>
   @foreach($sectionInfo as item)
     <li>{{ $item->titu_1_ing }}</li>
   @endforeach
</ul>
```

Con lo anterior hecho desde tu vista home ya podrías empezar a organizar la información del objeto, en una lista desordenada

Nota también que con el operador de la flecha simple accedo al nombre de cada columna que esta contenida en tu tabla.

Vas a colocar tantas etiquetas li como mostrar columnas de tu tabla necesites

Si por el contrario solo quieres mostrar datos específicos de tu tabla en tu vista, prueba del siguiente modo:

```
<h1>{{ $sectionInfo->titu_1_ing }}</h1>
```

Y lo anterior te debería funcionar

También en tu código al momento de usar el método compact, te esta haciendo falta meter entre comillas el nombre de la variable

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{       
    public function index()
    {
        $sectionInfo = Section::all();
        return view("home", compact('sectionInfo'));
    }
}
```

Saludos espero ser de ayuda

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, bueno solo quiero mostrar un registro en distintos elementos de mi vista pero intente con esto solo como prueba

<p><?php echo e($sectionInfo->titu_1_ing); ?></p>

pero me dice Undefined variable: sectionInfo (View: X:\Escritorio\pikum.backup\resources\views\home.blade.php)

Comment: prueba como lo agregue en la respuesta y me dices

Comment: te agregue unas observaciones nuevas en la respuesta espero las cheques

Comment: eres un duro! muchisimas gracias! :D por cierto si luego quiero actualizar esta informacion tendria que llamar luego otro metodo ?

Comment: vale jejejej si me puedes orientar : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/144178/update-laravel-desde-la-vista es mi primera vez en laravel y tampoco se mucho php solo lo toque una vez hace tiempisimo