# UPDATE Laravel desde la vista

Tags: laravel

tengo una vista que me trae los datos de mi db

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces lo que quiero ahora es actualizar mi db

```html
 <div class="col-10" id="side2">

            <div class="container" style="background-color: #e3e6e9; margin-top: 1rem; height:95%; padding: 2rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;">
                <div class="container" style="background-color: #f0f3f5; height: 100%; border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;">

                    <!-- TITLO -->
                    <div class="row justify-content-between" style="box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47);
                                                                            border-radius: 5px;
                                                                            background: #f0f3f5;
                                                                            padding: 0.7rem 0.2rem 0.2rem 0.2rem;">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <h4 style="color: #0b4650;"><strong>HOME/EDIT</strong></h4>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-6" style="text-align: right; padding-right: 3rem;">
                            <p style="color:gray;">ÚLTIMA EDICIÓN {{ $sectionInfo->updated_at }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- ___________________FORMULARIO___________________ -->
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('home') }}">

                        <!-- BOTONES GUARDAR / CERRAR -->
                        <div class="row" style="    text-align: right;
                                                    margin-top: 1rem;
                                                    margin-bottom: 1rem;">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <button type="button" class="btn" style="background: #065e6e; color: white; width: 7rem;">CERRAR</button>
                                <button type="SUBMIT" class="btn" style="background: #00a751; color: white; width: 7rem;">ACTUALIZAR</button>
                            </div>    
                        </div>

                        <!-- TITULOS -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6" style="padding-left: 3px; margin-bottom: 1rem;">
                                <input type="text" value="{{ $sectionInfo->titu_1_ing }}" style=" width: 100%;   padding: 0.3rem;   background: #e3e6e9;
                                                                                        border: solid 1px #8181825c;" text="PRIVATE ESCRUSSION IN SANTIAGO DE CHILE">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6" style="padding-right: 3px; margin-bottom: 1rem;">
                                <input type="text" value="{{ $sectionInfo->titu_1_esp }}" style="width: 100%; padding: 0.3rem;  background: #e3e6e9;
                                                                                    border: solid 1px #8181825c;">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- DESCRIPCION -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6" style="padding-left: 3px; margin-bottom: 1rem;">
                                <textarea name="message" rows="30" cols="80" style=" width: 100%; padding: 0.8rem;  height: 10rem; background: #e3e6e9; border: solid 1px #8181825c;">{{ $sectionInfo->desc_1_ing }}</textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6" style="padding-right: 3px; margin-bottom: 1rem;">
                                <textarea name="message" rows="30" cols="80" style=" width: 100%; padding: 0.8rem;  height: 10rem; background: #e3e6e9; border: solid 1px #8181825c;">{{ $sectionInfo->desc_1_esp }}</textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <hr/>
                        
                        <!-- CARGAR IMAGENES -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <h4>IMÁGENES DESKTOP</h4>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-6">
                                <h4>IMÁGENES MÓVIL</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" />
                                <br />
                                <div style="width: 5rem; height: 5rem;">
                                        <output id="list"></output>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" />
                                <br />
                                <output id="list"></output>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

y este es mi controlador

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Section;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $sectionInfo = Section::find(1);
        // let hora = $sectionInfo->updated_at;
        // hora = hora[9];
        // $sectionInfo->updated_at = hora;
        return view("home", compact('sectionInfo'));
    }
```

Ignoren la parte de las imagenes aun estoy trabajando en ello, lo que necesito saber es como actualizar mis campos en la db ????

**

### ACTUALIZACION

**
Hice lo siguiente, desde mi vista hice el formulario normal con los input que se llaman igual que mis columnas,

```html
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('home_update') }}">
         {{ csrf_field() }} 
                      <!-- TITULO -->
                      <div class="row justify-content-between" style="box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47);
                                                                              border-radius: 5px;
                                                                              background: #f0f3f5;
                                                                              padding: 0.7rem 0.2rem 0.2rem 0.2rem;">
                          <div class="col-6">
                              <h4 style="color: #0b4650;"><strong>HOME/EDIT</strong></h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-6" style="text-align: right; padding-right: 3rem;">
                              <input style="color: gray; border: none; width: 17rem; background: none;" value="ÚLTIMA EDICIÓN {{ $sectionInfo->updated_at }}" class="field left" readonly="readonly" name="updated_at">
                          </div>
                      </div>

                    

                        <!-- BOTONES GUARDAR / CERRAR -->
                        <div class="row" style="    text-align: right;
                                                    margin-top: 1rem;
                                                    margin-bottom: 1rem;">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <button type="button" class="btn" style="background: #065e6e; color: white; width: 7rem;">CERRAR</button>
                                <button type="SUBMIT" class="btn" style="background: #00a751; color: white; width: 7rem;">ACTUALIZAR</button>
                            </div>    
                        </div>

                        <!-- TITULOS -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6" style="padding-left: 3px; margin-bottom: 1rem;">
                                <input type="text" name="titu_1_ing" value="{{ $sectionInfo->titu_1_ing }}" style=" width: 100%;   padding: 0.3rem;   background: #e3e6e9;
                                                                                        border: solid 1px #8181825c;">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6" style="padding-right: 3px; margin-bottom: 1rem;">
                                <input type="text" name="titu_1_esp" value="{{ $sectionInfo->titu_1_esp }}" style="width: 100%; padding: 0.3rem;  background: #e3e6e9;
                                                                                    border: solid 1px #8181825c;">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- DESCRIPCION -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6" style="padding-left: 3px; margin-bottom: 1rem;">
                                <textarea name="desc_1_ing" rows="30" cols="80" style=" width: 100%; padding: 0.8rem;  height: 10rem; background: #e3e6e9; border: solid 1px #8181825c;">{{ $sectionInfo->desc_1_ing }}</textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6" style="padding-right: 3px; margin-bottom: 1rem;">
                                <textarea name="desc_1_esp" rows="30" cols="80" style=" width: 100%; padding: 0.8rem;  height: 10rem; background: #e3e6e9; border: solid 1px #8181825c;">{{ $sectionInfo->desc_1_esp }}</textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <hr/>
                        
                        <!-- CARGAR IMAGENES -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <h4>IMÁGENES DESKTOP</h4>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-6">
                                <h4>IMÁGENES MÓVIL</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" />
                                <br />
                                <div>
                                        <output id="list"></output>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" />
                                <br />
                                <div>
                                 <output id="list"></output>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
              </form>
```

todo bien hasta ahi, luego ese formulario llama la ruta **Route::POST('home_update', 'HomeController@update')->name('home_update');**

y en ese metodo tengo lo siguiente :

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
        $sectionInfo = Section::find(1);
        $section->titu_1_ing = request('titu_1_ing');
        $section->titu_1_esp = request('titu_1_esp');
        $section->desc_1_ing = request('desc_1_ing');
        $section->desc_1_esp = request('desc_1_esp');
        $section->save();
    return "Ok";
}
```

Siento que falta algo poruqe me sale el siguiente error: 
*"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Section' (T_STRING), expecting ')'"*

y apunta a la siguiente linea:
 *public function update(Request $request Section $sectionInfo)*

y si le quito el Section y el $sectionInfo me dice lo siguiente:
**"Creating default object from empty value"**

y apunta a la linea

*$section->titu_1_ing = request('titu_1_ing')*;

Comment: en un par de horas te comparto mi repósitorio para que cheques el ejemplo

Comment: ah vale tranquilo si hoy saldre del trabajo para la casa a seguir con esto :C

Comment: No es necesario todo un ejemplo tan grande y con otro contexto para algo tan sencillo como actualizar la base de datos.

Comment: ¿Revisaste la documentación? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#updates

Comment: si ya la estoy viendo, bueno no sabia que el updated_at se actualiza automaticamente, estoy viendo lo demas acabo de llgar a la casa jeje

Comment: hola, checa mi a ctualizacion si puedes, al final de mi pregunta, me podrias orientar ahi ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creo que hay alguna parte del código que no has puesto en tu pregunta, pero el problema está en los mensajes de error que copiaste.

> Siento que falta algo poruqe me sale el siguiente error: "Parse error:
>   syntax error, unexpected 'Section' (T_STRING), expecting ')'"
>
> y apunta a la siguiente linea: public function update(Request $request
>   Section $sectionInfo)

Lo que tenés que hacer es en la línea donde te marca el error
    `public function update(Request $request Section $sectionInfo)`
tenés que modificarlo por
    `public function update(Request $request, Section $sectionInfo)`.

El error de **unespected Section** es porque te falta la `coma`.